# Error on Visual Studio 2017/Windows 2012 - MFC does not support WINVER less than 0x0501

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, windows-server-2012

When I try to compile my Visual Studio C++ 2017, x86 application on Windows 2012 server, I am getting the below error

> Error C1189   #error:  MFC does not support WINVER less than 0x0501.
> Please change the definition of WINVER in your project properties or
> precompiled header.   MyProject   e:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual
> studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.13.26128\atlmfc\include\afxv_w32.h    40

I added the below code in the stadafx.h file. But it didn't resolve the issue.

```
    #ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
    #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x601
    #endif
```

How can I make sure that my code should work all the Windows operating systems equal or higher than Windows Server 2012?

> Project => Properties=> C/C++ => Precompiled Headers  values are empty.

The same code is working if I chose "Any CPU" build option.

Please let me know the correct configuration.

Comment: Do *not* use #ifndef when you want to make 100% sure that you define it, you'll now get compile warning when you redefine it.   And temporarily add #error "it works" to verify that this .h file actually gets included.

Answer (score 0):

You should define both _WIN32_WINNT and WINVER.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sehtctf.aspx

I usually put the definition in the preprocessor definitions part of project properties. Putting them in stdafx.h should work to, if all your cpp files include that as the 1st include in the file.